# Git - игнорировать содержимое файла, но проверять существование

Tags: git

Есть ли какой-нибудь вариант, чтобы Git следил за наличием/отсутствием файлов, но игнорировал их контент? Далее подробнее.

В проекте есть папка, условно, /inlude_content/. Файлы создаются разработчиком, подключаются к шаблону и содержат обычный контент.

Проблема: файлы могут меняться контент менеджером по несколько раз в день, и коммиты жирнеют от таких изменений. Версионировать содержимое файлов не нужно.

Если добавить папку в gitignore появляется другая проблема: я создаю новый модуль, подключаю для контентого содержимого этот файл, а потом вручную создаю пустые файлы с такими-же именами на сервере.

Может есть другие варианты решения моей проблемы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял что вам нужно, то можно так:

1. Папку добавляем в `.gitignore` так: `/dir_name/*`, т.е. игнорируем всё её содержимое.
2. Убираем из игнора нужный файл: `!/dir_name/file_name`
3. Пушим файл, например с пустым содержимым.
4. Указываем гиту чтобы он игнорировал последующие изменения в файле: `git update-index --assume-unchanged dir_name/file_name`

Answer (score 1):

Короткий ответ: через симлинки.

Вынесем весь контент в `content`, в нем и будет работать контент-менеджер.

Сделаем симлинки:

```
cd inlude_content
ln -s ../content/your-data.html
```

Каталог `content` добавить в `.gitignore`.

Создать файл `content/.gitkeep` и сделать `git add -f content/.gitkeep` - так добавим пустой каталог `content`.

Файлы есть - они "пустые" (симлинк является одним из видов файлов). Можно коммитить.

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов: добавить папку /inlude_content/ в gitignore на боевом сервере, но пушить в репозиторий из среды разработки пустые файлы.
Но в таком случае возникает проблема синхронизации самого gitignore, ведь его придется добавить в gitignore